# py2exe & win32 OLEObject error

Tags: python, py2exe, win32com, typelib

I have tried to compile my program into an exe with py2exe. Unfortunately, as I am using win32com to copy charts from Excel and embed them into PowerPoint using `(Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteOLEObject)`, I constantly get this error:

```
File "win32com\client\__init__.pyc", line 170, in __getattr__
AttributeError: ppPasteOLEObject`.
```

Googling hasn't really helped. The script works perfectly when I run it in python, so I know the problem is with win32com. Using makepy.py to include typelibs also didn't help, but maybe my `setup.py`is just wrong. So here it is:

```
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
from glob import glob
from os.path import normpath
import matplotlib

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)
data_files=[("Microsoft.VC90.CRT",glob(normpath(
    r'C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0/VC/redist/x86/Microsoft.VC90.CRT/*.*'))),
    ("images",glob(normpath("images/*.PNG"))),
    ("ppttemplate",glob(normpath("ppttemplate/*.pptx")),
    (".",normpath("C:/windows/system32/ole32.dll")),
    (".",normpath("C:/Anaconda2/envs/py27/Library/bin/MSVCP90.dll")))
    ]
data_files.extend(matplotlib.get_py2exe_datafiles())

setup(
    data_files=data_files,
    console=['Main.py'],
    options={"py2exe":{"includes":["lxml.etree","lxml._elementpath","gzip",
                       "sip","PyQt4.QtGui","PyQt4.QtCore","matplotlib"],
                       "excludes":["Tkinter"],
                       "typelibs":[('{2DF8D04C-5BFA-101B-BDE5-00AA0044DE52}', 0, 2, 8),
                                   ('{00020430-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}', 0, 2, 0)]
                                   }
                                   }
                                   )
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: For years I used Py2exe, finally after having countless errors and problems, I started using PyInstaller and it's been much better, try using https://mborgerson.com/creating-an-executable-from-a-python-script and see if that fixes the problem, if that fixes it, you're set, if not it could have to do with how it executes and no how it is packaged (IE, python runs in one directory, or with different permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! One just needs to inlude the relevant dlls and set `skip_archive=True`... (I included everything that py2exe was complaining about).

By adding:

```
sys.path.append("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VisualStudio9.0\\VC\\redist\\x86\\Microsoft.VC90.CRT")
sys.path.append("C:\\windows\\system32")
```

before the `data_files` line and adding all the `system32` to `data_files` and adding `skip_archive=True` inside `py2exe:` it worked! 
Hopefully it functions on different computers as well...

The guide I used was on the website of [py2exe] (http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/IncludingTypelibs)!